What are the keyboard shortcuts for "Go Back" and "Go Forward" in the Tips (com.apple.helpviewer) app (AKA "Help" or "Help Viewer" app)?
When clicking on the "Help" menu in any app and then clicking the "Get Help" (or similarly phrased) menu item, the "Tips" app opens. I believe this app was previously called "Help" or "Help Viewer" (the package name for the "Tips" app is "com.apple.helpviewer"). I'm using macOS Sequoia 15.1 Developer Beta on a 2020 MacBook Pro M1. Does anyone know what this app's keyboard shortcuts are for "Go Back" and "Go Forward"?
